# html and python wrapping

Tags: html, python-2.7

i have main.html page where i have 3 href link.
and i have my data in excel file with 3 columns.
what i want to  do is when i click on the link in main.html it should fetch data in excel file by using python and display it in html page on browser.

this is what i have written now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="HOME.css" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Racdm GUI</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="navigation_bar">
<ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="HOME.html">iDRAC</a></li>
    <li><a href="System.html">System</a></li>
    <li><a href="LifeCycleControler.html">Life Cycle Controller</a></li>
    <li><a href="#BIOS">BIOS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#NIC">NIC</a></li>
    <li><a href="#STORAGE">STORAGE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#FC">FC</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i want to work on the first 3 link first then i can populate remaining links

Comment: could you show us what you have tried so far? What python script did you create to read the data from the excel files? What kind of server are you asking the data from?